# Hide first image inside a div where the image is not a direct child

Tags: css, css-selectors

We are trying to hide all but the first image for each 
**mydiv** without hiding any of the text  given the following html:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>
        <img  src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" />
    </p>
    <p>text
        <img  src="http://placekitten.com/250/200" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" />
    </p>
    <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>
         text
    </p>
    <p>text
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/200" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <img  src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is an example on 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84dj6gwb/2/).

We would like to avoid altering the original html(because it is generated from a wiswig editor).
We cannot hide any of the text so hiding the entire paragraph is out of the question.

I basically want this functionality to work

```
div.mydiv p img ~ div.mydiv p img {
   display: none;
}
```

This does not work since the images are not direct siblings.

Comment: That's right, and there is no parent selector in CSS, so you're out of luck. Sorry! Solution: JavaScript.

Comment: Agree with @MrLister, you need a script to do that

Comment: div.mydiv p:first-child  img {
   display: none;
}  try this

Comment: @divya What's the point guessing, if you try yourself you'll see it does not work

Comment: Sorry for my answer. Actually i have not seen the 2nd part.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try a ~ ?

Is

```
.mydiv p img{ display:none; }
```

not sufficient ?

[EDIT] 
Sorry, didn't understood what you want,

try this

```
.mydiv p img{ display:none; }
.mydiv p:first-child img{ display:block; }
```

Comment: Does not work either, as script is needed to do this

Comment: This would work assuming the first p tag of each mydiv had an image.  Sometimes the users add text to the first p tag (and no image) so this won't work for me.

Comment: Did you miss _to hide all but the first image for each **mydiv**_ ?? ... so I'm telling you, this can't be done without script (today)

Comment: @DanielCumings, if the first p tag has no images, it would do nothing. pointing the p:first-child img should point only the image in the first p tag (if it exists), no ?

Comment: Ok, sorry, didn't understood.

Comment: When all is done and said it should show two kittens.  If there is no easy way to do this (besides javascript) we have an alternative solution.  I was just frustrated because I could not find an easy solution to this that did not involve code.

Answer (score 1):

Using js:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css it will work 100% correctly. i have tried that.

```
 .mydiv p
    {
     display:inline-block;
    }


    .mydiv:first-child p:first-child img{ display:none; }
```

Comment: For this a script is needed